# Send a dynamic id to a Simple Modal confirm dialog confirmation

Tags: modal-dialog, simplemodal

I see how the Simple Modal example is working, but I don't see a way to send an id to it.
I have a recordset on my page with many rows that have a delete button for each. I need to send the id for each one to the modal function to attach the id to the url when redirected.

Here is the [example site](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/). It's the Confirm Override one.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see an example of what you are trying to do.